# Concatenating File Path Excel

Tags: excel

Lets say I have columns with dates on them.
The file path is something like this:

='U:\Report\[Date 042516.xls]Joe Smoe'!$C81

Where the '042516' is variable to each column. !$C81 is variable to each row in the original document.

How do I do this and pull up the respective numbers from the reports and dates?

Comment: Try INDIRECT.  also a small example table maybe 2X3 would be a great help in making your question clearer

Comment: TLDR: I have a path. The only thing I need to change in the path for each column is the date part (e.g., 042516) with the respective column. How do I do this?

Comment: Visualization of data:

    02162016;
    insert path here

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand - so you have a column with numbers (`042516`,`042517`,`042518`, etc), and you want the formula to update that part of the path, as you drag down?

If your `042516` is in `C1`, you can use this:

`=INDIRECT("'U:\Report\[Date "&C1&".xls]Joe Smoe'!$C81")`
(Note the workbook being referenced, `Date 042516.xls`, must be open for Indirect to work.)

Comment: does it need to be open when specifying the full path from the drive letter?

Comment: @ForwardEd - As far as I know and have experienced, `Indirect()` requires the book to be open, even with the full path.  That's not to say there may be some clever workaround, but by default it needs to be open. [Here's](http://superuser.com/a/535924/529100) a little more info, from SuperUser.

Comment: I recalled it needing to be open, but there was something in the back of my head that some functions (not sure which) will work with full path file closed, but will not work with only file name closed.  was not sure if this was that function or not.

Comment: Then again the back of my head is not the most reliable source of intel.